# Optimize wordpress class code to avoid redundance

Tags: php, wordpress

I have now finished a simple training on wordpress plugin creation. I've created a simple plugin that will register some custom shortcodes to use bootstrap classes inside the WordPress editor. 
I want to make the plugin code more readable and less prone to redundant code. For now I have this single function that is wrapping all the major classes I use in my layouts, but I think that it's too complex from the readability perspective.

Is there a better way to write the code? I'm thinking to create some files to include using `require_once` or with the `include` function inside the class method but I'm not sure if it will work, this because I'm using the output buffer to display the html code. 
Another solution I want to test is to separate the various columns layout into single class methods, but I'm not sure about.

I'm using it in a test page in this way:

```
[page_col type="col-6" mobile="hide"]the post or page content[/page_col]
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

```
public function pageCol($atts, $content)
  {
    ob_start();
    $content = strip_tags($content, '<p><span><div><img>');
    $val = shortcode_atts(array(
        'type' => 'col-12',
        'mobile' => 'display'
    ),$atts);

    if( $val['mobile'] === 'hide' ){
      switch($val['type']){
        case 'col-3':
        ?>
          <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 d-none d-sm-none d-md-block">
            <?php echo $content; ?>
          </div>
        <?php
          return ob_get_clean();
          break;
        case 'col-4':
        ?>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 d-none d-sm-none d-md-block">
            <?php echo $content; ?>
          </div>
        <?php
          return ob_get_clean();
          break;
        case 'col-6':
        ?>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 d-none d-sm-none d-md-block">
            <?php echo $content; ?>
          </div>
        <?php
          return ob_get_clean();
          break;
        case 'col-8':
          ?>
          <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 d-none d-sm-none d-md-block">
            <?php echo $content; ?>
          </div>
          <?php
          return ob_get_clean();
          break;
        case 'col-12':
          ?>
          <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 d-none d-sm-none d-md-block">
            <?php echo $content; ?>
          </div>
          <?php
          return ob_get_clean();
          break;
      }
    }
    else{
      switch($val['type']){
        case 'col-3':
        ?>
// I want to require the file instead of writing the code inside the switch() statement
// example: include 'my-col-layout.php';
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <?php echo $content; ?>
          </div>
        <?php
          return ob_get_clean();
          break;
        case 'col-4':
        ?>
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <?php echo $content; ?>
          </div>
        <?php
          return ob_get_clean();
          break;
        case 'col-6':
        ?>
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <?php echo $content; ?>
          </div>
        <?php
          return ob_get_clean();
          break;
        case 'col-8':
        ?>
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
            <?php echo $content; ?>
          </div>
        <?php
          return ob_get_clean();
          break;
        case 'col-12':
        ?>
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <?php echo $content; ?>
          </div>
        <?php
          return ob_get_clean();
          break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is way too broad of a question. How does this function get used? We have no idea how you're implementing it.

Comment: @disinfor It's part of a class that is registering the shortcode. It's used to style the content of the wordpress editor using the bootstrap 4 classes example `[page_col type="col-6" mobile="hide"]some content[/page_col]`

Comment: Edit your question to add that information.

Comment: @disinfor question edited. The function is only a part of the complete class that is containing others methods like the one I've posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is pretty much overkill. There is no reason for the `switch` statement at all since your `col-md` and `col-lg` share the same value. You can also lose the `ob_start()`.

I think you should also reformat how you used the shortcode, so the user only has to enter the column number, e.g. `6` vs. `col-6`, that way you can insert just that value into the `col-md-##`.

```
[page_col type="6" mobile="hide"]the post or page content[/page_col]

public function pageCol($atts, $content) {

    $content = strip_tags($content, '<p><span><div><img>');

    $val = shortcode_atts(array(
        'type' => '12',
        'mobile' => 'display'
    ),$atts);

    $output = '';

    if( $val['mobile'] === 'hide' ){
        $output = '<div class="col-md-' . $val['type'] . ' col-lg-' . $val['type'] . ' d-none d-sm-none d-md-block">' . $content . '</div>';
    } else {
        $output = '<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-' . $val['type'] .' col-lg-' . $val['type'] . '">' . $content . '</div>';
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm using the output buffer because initially the content wasn't outputted, this because wordpress require that a string is returned from the callback function. I will semplify my code as yuo suggest, just one thing, would be better approach if I include the files with the markup instead of adding the html code into the function?

Comment: No it would not be a better approach for this to use `includes`, since this is exactly what shortcodes are for. And since the shortcode will return a single line of HTML, it would be, again, overkill. You can put the output buffer back in if you are going to return the actual page content.

Comment: With this code style, inside the returned variable I can also use a `do_shortcode($content)` or i need to echo it like `'<div>' echo do_shortcode($content); '</div>'`?

Comment: You do not need to `echo` it. In fact, that will break it. When you use a shortcode in the WYSIWYG, it echoes.